# Trying to dynamically resize height of iframe that is pointing to a local PHP page

Tags: javascript, iframe, resize, height

I've read through tons of posts and articles and haven't found a fix that works specifically for my problem

My parent page points via iframe to a local child page.

The child page is a php survey which changes height from page to page as the user clicks the next button. (Not really changing pages but re-populating content within one .php file)

I'm trying to have the parent page auto expand and contact height according to the length of the child page.

I have this specific need because I'm working within WordPress and want a PHP application (survey) to be wrapped within the design of the WordPress theme.

Ay help would be really appreciated!

Comment: If it is local. Why are you using an iFrame? Why don't you use separate pages using query strings? Or AJAX loading is also an option..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are the two pages on the same domain? If yes, then the easiest way to achieve this is with JavaScript running on both the parent and the child page.

Here's a rough idea of how it might work. On the child page:

```
...
<script>
  function resizeFrame() {
    // Call out to the parent iframe.
    window.parent.resizeChild(document.body.clientHeight);
 }
</script>
...
<body onload="resizeFrame()">
...
```

On the parent page:

```
<script>
  function resizeChild(height) {
    // Add the ID of the iframe element below.
    document.getElementById(...).style.height = height + 'px';
  }
</script>
```

You'll probably need to adjust the height, depending on the margins/borders/etc of the iframe element.

If the two pages are on different domains, this will be much harder. Cross-domain communication between `iframes` is difficult, particularly if you want to support older browsers.